# Calculate rolling window Max DrawDown in C#

Tags: c#, statistics, finance, quantitative-finance

The requirement is to compute the maximum drawdown for a rolling window in C# for a timeseries of e.g. returns.
I.e. at each new observation, we recompute the maximum drawdown for the new time window.

Answer (score 5):

Hello people.
This is quite a complex problem if you want to solve this in a computationally efficient way for a rolling window.
I have gone ahead and written a solution to this in C#.
I want to share this as the effort required to replicate this work is quite high.

First, here are the results:

> here we take a simple drawdown implementation and re-calculate for the full window each time

```
test1 - simple drawdown test with 30 period rolling window. run 100 times.
total seconds 0.8060461
test2 - simple drawdown test with 60 period rolling window. run 100 times.
total seconds 1.416081
test3 - simple drawdown test with 180 period rolling window. run 100 times.
total seconds 3.6602093
test4 - simple drawdown test with 360 period rolling window. run 100 times.
total seconds 6.696383
test5 - simple drawdown test with 500 period rolling window. run 100 times.
total seconds 8.9815137
```

> here we compare to the results generated from my efficient rolling window algorithm where only the latest observation is added and then it does it's magic

```
test6 - running drawdown test with 30 period rolling window. run 100 times.
total seconds 0.2940168
test7 - running drawdown test with 60 period rolling window. run 100 times.
total seconds 0.3050175
test8 - running drawdown test with 180 period rolling window. run 100 times.
total seconds 0.3780216
test9 - running drawdown test with 360 period rolling window. run 100 times.
total seconds 0.4560261
test10 - running drawdown test with 500 period rolling window. run 100 times.
total seconds 0.5050288
```

> At at 500 period window. We are achieving about a 20:1 improvement in calculation time.

Here is the code of the simple drawdown class used for the comparisons:

```
public class SimpleDrawDown
{
    public double Peak { get; set; }
    public double Trough { get; set; }
    public double MaxDrawDown { get; set; }

    public SimpleDrawDown()
    {
        Peak = double.NegativeInfinity;
        Trough = double.PositiveInfinity;
        MaxDrawDown = 0;
    }

    public void Calculate(double newValue)
    {
        if (newValue > Peak)
        {
            Peak = newValue;
            Trough = Peak;
        }
        else if (newValue < Trough)
        {
            Trough = newValue;
            var tmpDrawDown = Peak - Trough;
            if (tmpDrawDown > MaxDrawDown)
                MaxDrawDown = tmpDrawDown;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the code for the full efficient implementation. Hopefully the code comments make sense.

```
internal class DrawDown
{
    int _n;
    int _startIndex, _endIndex, _troughIndex;
    public int Count { get; set; }
    LinkedList<double> _values;
    public double Peak { get; set; }
    public double Trough { get; set; }
    public bool SkipMoveBackDoubleCalc { get; set; }

    public int PeakIndex
    {
        get
        {
            return _startIndex;
        }
    }
    public int TroughIndex
    {
        get
        {
            return _troughIndex;
        }
    }

    //peak to trough return
    public double DrawDownAmount
    {
        get
        {
            return Peak - Trough;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="n">max window for drawdown period</param>
    /// <param name="peak">drawdown peak i.e. start value</param>
    public DrawDown(int n, double peak)
    {
        _n = n - 1;
        _startIndex = _n;
        _endIndex = _n;
        _troughIndex = _n;
        Count = 1;
        _values = new LinkedList<double>();
        _values.AddLast(peak);
        Peak = peak;
        Trough = peak;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// adds a new observation on the drawdown curve
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="newValue"></param>
    public void Add(double newValue)
    {
        //push the start of this drawdown backwards
        //_startIndex--;
        //the end of the drawdown is the current period end
        _endIndex = _n;
        //the total periods increases with a new observation
        Count++;
        //track what all point values are in the drawdown curve
        _values.AddLast(newValue);
        //update if we have a new trough
        if (newValue < Trough)
        {
            Trough = newValue;
            _troughIndex = _endIndex;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Shift this Drawdown backwards in the observation window
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="trackingNewPeak">whether we are already tracking a new peak or not</param>
    /// <returns>a new drawdown to track if a new peak becomes active</returns>
    public DrawDown MoveBack(bool trackingNewPeak, bool recomputeWindow = true)
    {
        if (!SkipMoveBackDoubleCalc)
        {
            _startIndex--;
            _endIndex--;
            _troughIndex--;
            if (recomputeWindow)
                return RecomputeDrawdownToWindowSize(trackingNewPeak);
        }
        else
            SkipMoveBackDoubleCalc = false;

        return null;
    }

    private DrawDown RecomputeDrawdownToWindowSize(bool trackingNewPeak)
    {
        //the start of this drawdown has fallen out of the start of our observation window, so we have to recalculate the peak of the drawdown
        if (_startIndex < 0)
        {
            Peak = double.NegativeInfinity;
            _values.RemoveFirst();
            Count--;

            //there is the possibility now that there is a higher peak, within the current drawdown curve, than our first observation
            //when we find it, remove all data points prior to this point
            //the new peak must be before the current known trough point
            int iObservation = 0, iNewPeak = 0, iNewTrough = _troughIndex, iTmpNewPeak = 0, iTempTrough = 0;
            double newDrawDown = 0, tmpPeak = 0, tmpTrough = double.NegativeInfinity;
            DrawDown newDrawDownObj = null;
            foreach (var pointOnDrawDown in _values)
            {
                if (iObservation < _troughIndex)
                {
                    if (pointOnDrawDown > Peak)
                    {
                        iNewPeak = iObservation;
                        Peak = pointOnDrawDown;
                    }
                }
                else if (iObservation == _troughIndex)
                {
                    newDrawDown = Peak - Trough;
                    tmpPeak = Peak;
                }
                else
                {
                    //now continue on through the remaining points, to determine if there is a nested-drawdown, that is now larger than the newDrawDown
                    //e.g. higher peak beyond _troughIndex, with higher trough than that at _troughIndex, but where new peak minus new trough is > newDrawDown
                    if (pointOnDrawDown > tmpPeak)
                    {
                        tmpPeak = pointOnDrawDown;
                        tmpTrough = tmpPeak;
                        iTmpNewPeak = iObservation;
                        //we need a new drawdown object, as we have a new higher peak
                        if (!trackingNewPeak) 
                            newDrawDownObj = new DrawDown(_n + 1, tmpPeak);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (!trackingNewPeak && newDrawDownObj != null)
                        {
                            newDrawDownObj.MoveBack(true, false); //recomputeWindow is irrelevant for this as it will never fall before period 0 in this usage scenario
                            newDrawDownObj.Add(pointOnDrawDown);  //keep tracking this new drawdown peak
                        }

                        if (pointOnDrawDown < tmpTrough)
                        {
                            tmpTrough = pointOnDrawDown;
                            iTempTrough = iObservation;
                            var tmpDrawDown = tmpPeak - tmpTrough;

                            if (tmpDrawDown > newDrawDown)
                            {
                                newDrawDown = tmpDrawDown;
                                iNewPeak = iTmpNewPeak;
                                iNewTrough = iTempTrough;
                                Peak = tmpPeak;
                                Trough = tmpTrough;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                iObservation++;
            }

            _startIndex = iNewPeak; //our drawdown now starts from here in our observation window
            _troughIndex = iNewTrough;
            for (int i = 0; i < _startIndex; i++)
            {
                _values.RemoveFirst(); //get rid of the data points prior to this new drawdown peak
                Count--;
            }
            return newDrawDownObj;
        }
        return null;
    }

}

public class RunningDrawDown
{

    int _n;
    List<DrawDown> _drawdownObjs;
    DrawDown _currentDrawDown;
    DrawDown _maxDrawDownObj;

    /// <summary>
    /// The Peak of the MaxDrawDown
    /// </summary>
    public double DrawDownPeak
    {
        get
        {
            if (_maxDrawDownObj == null) return double.NegativeInfinity;
            return _maxDrawDownObj.Peak;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// The Trough of the Max DrawDown
    /// </summary>
    public double DrawDownTrough
    {
        get
        {
            if (_maxDrawDownObj == null) return double.PositiveInfinity;
            return _maxDrawDownObj.Trough;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// The Size of the DrawDown - Peak to Trough
    /// </summary>
    public double DrawDown
    {
        get
        {
            if (_maxDrawDownObj == null) return 0;
            return _maxDrawDownObj.DrawDownAmount;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// The Index into the Window that the Peak of the DrawDown is seen
    /// </summary>
    public int PeakIndex
    {
        get
        {
            if (_maxDrawDownObj == null) return 0;
            return _maxDrawDownObj.PeakIndex;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// The Index into the Window that the Trough of the DrawDown is seen
    /// </summary>
    public int TroughIndex
    {
        get
        {
            if (_maxDrawDownObj == null) return 0;
            return _maxDrawDownObj.TroughIndex;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a running window for the calculation of MaxDrawDown within the window
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="n">the number of periods within the window</param>
    public RunningDrawDown(int n)
    {
        _n = n;
        _currentDrawDown = null;
        _drawdownObjs = new List<DrawDown>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The new value to add onto the end of the current window (the first value will drop off)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="newValue">the new point on the curve</param>
    public void Calculate(double newValue)
    {
        if (double.IsNaN(newValue)) return;

        if (_currentDrawDown == null)
        {
            var drawDown = new DrawDown(_n, newValue);
            _currentDrawDown = drawDown;
            _maxDrawDownObj = drawDown;
        }
        else
        {
            //shift current drawdown back one. and if the first observation falling outside the window means we encounter a new peak after the current trough, we start tracking a new drawdown
            var drawDownFromNewPeak = _currentDrawDown.MoveBack(false);

            //this is a special case, where a new lower peak (now the highest) is created due to the drop of of the pre-existing highest peak, and we are not yet tracking a new peak
            if (drawDownFromNewPeak != null)
            {
                _drawdownObjs.Add(_currentDrawDown); //record this drawdown into our running drawdowns list)
                _currentDrawDown.SkipMoveBackDoubleCalc = true; //MoveBack() is calculated again below in _drawdownObjs collection, so we make sure that is skipped this first time
                _currentDrawDown = drawDownFromNewPeak;
                _currentDrawDown.MoveBack(true);
            }

            if (newValue > _currentDrawDown.Peak)
            {
                //we need a new drawdown object, as we have a new higher peak
                var drawDown = new DrawDown(_n, newValue);
                //do we have an existing drawdown object, and does it have more than 1 observation
                if (_currentDrawDown.Count > 1)
                {
                    _drawdownObjs.Add(_currentDrawDown); //record this drawdown into our running drawdowns list)
                    _currentDrawDown.SkipMoveBackDoubleCalc = true; //MoveBack() is calculated again below in _drawdownObjs collection, so we make sure that is skipped this first time
                }
                _currentDrawDown = drawDown;
            }
            else
            {
                //add the new observation to the current drawdown
                _currentDrawDown.Add(newValue);
            }
        }

        //does our new drawdown surpass any of the previous drawdowns?
        //if so, we can drop the old drawdowns, as for the remainer of the old drawdowns lives in our lookup window, they will be smaller than the new one
        var newDrawDown = _currentDrawDown.DrawDownAmount;
        _maxDrawDownObj = _currentDrawDown;
        var maxDrawDown = newDrawDown;
        var keepDrawDownsList = new List<DrawDown>();
        foreach (var drawDownObj in _drawdownObjs)
        {
            drawDownObj.MoveBack(true);
            if (drawDownObj.DrawDownAmount > newDrawDown)
            {
                keepDrawDownsList.Add(drawDownObj);
            }

            //also calculate our max drawdown here
            if (drawDownObj.DrawDownAmount > maxDrawDown)
            {
                maxDrawDown = drawDownObj.DrawDownAmount;
                _maxDrawDownObj = drawDownObj;
            }

        }
        _drawdownObjs = keepDrawDownsList;

    }

}
```

Example usage:

```
RunningDrawDown rd = new RunningDrawDown(500);
foreach (var input in data)
{
    rd.Calculate(input);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("max draw {0:0.00000}, peak {1:0.00000}, trough {2:0.00000}, drawstart {3:0.00000}, drawend {4:0.00000}",
        rd.DrawDown, rd.DrawDownPeak, rd.DrawDownTrough, rd.PeakIndex, rd.TroughIndex));
}
```

Comment: btw the total datasize was about 8000 observations, so that time is based on about 8000 iterations of window size x 100.

Comment: It would be nice and helpful to post actual inputs and outputs. If they are small than right here SO is fine. I think this way people can validate and make sense of the algorithm

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need a rolling window calculation (which can be handled outside) - here is a much more compact code.

I also added a function for finding the largest **percentage** drop, as well as the largest absolute drop.

Both functions return percentage and absolute drawdown.

```
/// <summary>
/// Finds the largest percentage loss from a peak to a trough, before a new peak is attained.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>Drawdown percentage and amount</returns>
public static MaxDrawdown CalculateMaxPercentageDrawdown(IList<double> values) => CalculateMaxDrawdown(values, byPercentage: true);
/// <summary>
/// Finds the largest loss (in absolute numbers, for example USD) from a peak to a trough, before a new peak is attained.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>Drawdown percentage and amount</returns>
public static MaxDrawdown CalculateMaxAmountDrawdown(IList<double> values) => CalculateMaxDrawdown(values, byPercentage: false);

private static MaxDrawdown CalculateMaxDrawdown(IList<double> values, bool byPercentage)
{
    if (values.Count() == 0) return new MaxDrawdown(0, 0);
    if (values.First() == 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("Cannot calculate drawdown percentage where the initial value is zero, dividing any loss with zero results in \"infinite\" loss.", nameof(values));

    double maxPeak = double.NaN;
    double maxAmountDrop = double.MinValue;
    double maxPercentageDrawdown = double.MaxValue;
    double percentageDrawdown = double.MaxValue;
    double maxPercentageDropInAmount = 0;
    foreach (var change in values)
    {
        if (double.IsNaN(maxPeak))
        { //first value is always the first peak
            maxPeak = change;
            continue;
        }
        var amountDrawdown = maxPeak - change;
        maxPeak = amountDrawdown < 0 ? change : maxPeak;

        if (maxAmountDrop < amountDrawdown & amountDrawdown > 0)
        {
            //new low drop in amount
            maxAmountDrop = amountDrawdown;
            percentageDrawdown = (maxAmountDrop / maxPeak) * -1d;
        }

        //if we're finding the largest ABSOLUTE/AMOUNT drop (not percentage), use this value as the new percentage drop
        //if we're finding the largest PERCENTAGE drop, we need to check if this is the new maximum percentage drop
        if (!byPercentage || percentageDrawdown < maxPercentageDrawdown)
        {
            maxPercentageDrawdown = percentageDrawdown;
            maxPercentageDropInAmount = maxAmountDrop;
        }


    }
    double percentage = maxPercentageDrawdown != double.MaxValue && maxPercentageDrawdown < 0 ? Math.Abs(maxPercentageDrawdown) : 0;
    maxAmountDrop = maxAmountDrop != double.MinValue && maxAmountDrop > 0 ? maxAmountDrop : 0;
    maxPercentageDropInAmount = maxPercentageDropInAmount != double.MinValue && maxPercentageDropInAmount > 0 ? maxPercentageDropInAmount : 0;

    if (byPercentage)
        return new MaxDrawdown(drawdownPercentage: percentage, drawdownAmount: maxPercentageDropInAmount);
    else
        return new MaxDrawdown(drawdownPercentage: percentage, drawdownAmount: maxAmountDrop);
}

public class MaxDrawdown
{
    public MaxDrawdown(double drawdownPercentage, double drawdownAmount) { DrawdownPercentage = drawdownPercentage; DrawdownAmount = drawdownAmount; }
    public double DrawdownPercentage { get; private set; }
    public double DrawdownAmount { get; private set; }
}

[Test]
public void TestAmountVsPercentage()
{
    var increasingPeaks = new List<double>() {
        10, //first peak
        4, //lowest percentage drop, 60% 6
        100, //highest peak
        50, //lowest drop by amount, 50% 50
    };
    var rdPercentage = CalculateMaxPercentageDrawdown(increasingPeaks);
    Assert.That(rdPercentage.DrawdownAmount, Is.EqualTo(6));
    Assert.That(rdPercentage.DrawdownPercentage, Is.EqualTo(0.60));

    var rdAmount = CalculateMaxAmountDrawdown(increasingPeaks);
    Assert.That(rdAmount.DrawdownAmount, Is.EqualTo(50));
    Assert.That(rdAmount.DrawdownPercentage, Is.EqualTo(0.5));
}
```